# (Android opencv) Undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorMatcher::knnMatch`

Tags: android, opencv, surf

I compiling my Android project via jni (OpenCV with contrib).

Everything is OK, but I have a one problem. Every sources are doing well but only cv::DescriptorMatcher::knnMatch is not.

Here is my build error:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication5\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a --target native-lib}
[1/1] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libnative-lib.so
FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=aarch64-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11  -std=gnu++11 -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -nostdlib++ --sysroot C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -LC:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a     -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o  ../../../../src/main/JniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java3.so -llog -latomic -lm "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a/libc++_static.a" "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a/libc++abi.a" && cd ."
CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o: In function `Java_com_example_user_myapplication_MainActivity_SurfTest':
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication5\app\src\main\cpp/native-lib.cpp:191: undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorMatcher::knnMatch(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::__ndk1::vector<std::__ndk1::vector<cv::DMatch, std::__ndk1::allocator<cv::DMatch> >, std::__ndk1::allocator<std::__ndk1::vector<cv::DMatch, std::__ndk1::allocator<cv::DMatch> > > >&, int, cv::_InputArray const&, bool) const'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

It seems like linker error, but I can't solve it.
Anyone who knows?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it my self.

if you use Android sdk with CMAKE, you can change your compile method(?) CMAKE to Android.mk

then, you can..

Comment: can you share your Android.mk and Application.mk files here please, I'm running into the same issue